# Web API model binding not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-binding

Why is Web API model binding so complicated by default:
I tried a lot of combinations but none of them seem to work.
This is ajax request:

```
var dataString = JSON.stringify({
            request: Request
        });
var request = Request;
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: '='+dataString,
        // contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
```

This is controller:

```
public AccResultObject Post(string jezik, string page, string size, string sort,AccRequestViewModel model)
```

This is AccRequestViewModel

```
public class AccRequestViewModel
{
    public AccRequestObject request { get; set; }
}
```

and  this is AccRequestObject:

```
public class AccRequestObject
    {

        public int FM { get; set; }
        public int Budget { get; set; }
        public string WebCatID { get; set; }


        public int Distance { get; set; }
    }
```

Whatever I do, controller gets null value.

I tried this also. It seems very logical:

```
 var dataString = JSON.stringify({
            request: Request
         });
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: dataString, ...
```

and controller receives AccRequestObject:

```
  public AccResultObject Post(string jezik, string page, string size, string sort,[FromBody] AccRequestObjectmodel)
```

It works great except this small problem. Values are not binded.

Comment: What is the structure of the "Request" which is being stringified? You also don't need to prepend '=' to the data part of the ajax call.

Comment: I find out that I need to prepend '=' in WEB API

Comment: You shouldn't need to and as you're getting nulls in the binder maybe try removing it :-) Please provide the json you are trying to POST as without it it's hard to determine the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the properties of each object you are creating in javascript match exactly to the code model.  If a property name is uppercase in the code model, it needs to be uppercase in the js.  Other than that, to post a model with jquery to a Web Api controller is pretty simple:

```
//code model
public class MyModel{
    public int MyProperty{get;set;}     
}

//js
$.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://api/to/my/controller',
        data: JSON.stringify({MyProperty: 1}),
        type: "POST"
    });
```

Comment: can we somehow avoid having the uppercase in the js? Setting the jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(); does not work.

Comment: @MilenKovachev Id imagine you could write your own:  http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm

Answer (score 1):

In the C#, make sure your properties are public [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/members), not [fields](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690403/Public-Field-Not-Bound-When-Pos).

```
public class MyBindingModel
{
    public string myProp{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: They need to be public as well.